# Make PHP run after form submitted without redirecting to another PHP page to process the data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate question due to the fact that I'm not even sure how to properly form it (That's why the title of this question makes no real sense). I am beginning to learn PHP so I can utilize SQL databases in my webpages.

My question is, how would I be able to make it so a user types in a password into an input box, which is then used by a PHP script as the password to a MySQL login to display the contents of a table in an HTML table? Now, I have most of this figured out, the only problem is displaying the table on the same page which the password is entered and the submit button is hit. Would I need to use AJAX? Because I don't know the first thing about it. Here is what I have so far:

Index.php:

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Guy's Random Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<form action="" method="POST">
<font size="4">Password: </font><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass"/><br>
<input class="buttonGreen" type="submit" value="Submit" id="1" onMouseDown="mouseDown(1)" onMouseOut="mouseUp(1)"/>
</form>
</div>

<table><thead><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Rating</th></thead><tbody>
<?php include 'getTableData.php'?>
</tbody></table>


</body>
</html>
```

getTableData.php:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = $_POST['pass'];;
$dbname = "testing";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, type, rating FROM crap_food";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["type"] . "</td><td>" . $row["rating"] . "</td></tr>";
     }
} else {
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I understand the fact that PHP is run server side, and is only run before any HTML is read by the client, so making a function run when a button is hit wouldn't exactly be possible just using PHP and HTML, but this would be similar to what I'm looking for. I don't want to redirect the user to another page via the form action (Which is why it's blank), I want to keep this all within index.php. Thanks (And sorry for the horrible forming of this question, I'm just a bit confused).

Comment: try to do this using ajax

Comment: Darn, that's what I thought the answer would be. Welp, time to learn all about AJAX.

Comment: Ajax is one option. But also google for websockets, socket.io, single page apps, react and angularjs.

Comment: Please refer @Gordon's comment instead of mine :p +1 sir

Comment: Sure, I'll check out AngularJS, I've heard a bunch about it.

Answer (score 0):

You Use AJAX for this.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'xxx.php',

    data:formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response)
    {
            //do something 

    }
```

Comment: You're actually using *jQuery library*, which does AJAX. `$.ajax` is not available if you don't load jQuery in the HTML page. Seeing as the OP is just learning, maybe it's better to spell it out.

Comment: than you can load jquery library. and than use it

Comment: Thanks, I'm already reading up on W3schools, and it seems perfect. The line "AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging data with a web server behind the scenes." describes exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    $password =$_POST['pass'];
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username,$password);

$sql = 'SELECT firstname FROM users';

$q = $conn->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($r = $q->fetch()): 
    echo ($r['firstname']);
    echo "<tr><td>" . ($r['firstname']) . "</td></tr>";
endwhile;

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
   die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" .$pe->getMessage());
}
?>
```